# How do I get the container ID of a non-running container?

Tags: docker

I was updating a docker image from a container shell via

```
docker run -it <image_name> /bin/bash -l
```

I've exited the container and now want to commit the changes with

```
docker commit -m 'changes' -a 'me' <container ID> <image name>
```

But I don't have access to the container ID anymore? `docker ps` only lists running containers. How can I get the ID of the stopped container?

Answer (score 7):

Getting the container ID is really simple:

```
docker ps --all
```

The `-a` or `--all` flag to `docker ps` lists all containers, not just the running one.

If you want only the ID of the most-recently exited container, you can use

```
docker ps --all -q | head -1
```

This can be handy to use in the `docker commit` command so you can easily commit the latest changes by just pressing up a few times and changing the commit message:

```
docker commit -m 'changes' -a 'me' "$(docker ps --all -q | head -1)" <image name>
```

Answer (score 2):

`docker ps -l` (or `--latest`) will return the container that was last run (also if that container is no longer running).

To get just the `ID`, add the `-q` flag, so `docker ps -l -q` (or `docker ps -lq` will give you the `ID` of the last run container

Answer (score 0):

If you control the way your run the container, you can tell Docker to save container ID to the file ([docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#cidfile)):

> `--cidfile` Write the container ID to the file
> [...]
> The `cidfile` flag makes Docker attempt to create a new file and write the container ID to it. If the file exists already, Docker returns an error. Docker closes this file when docker run exits.

For instance:

```
docker run --cidfile cid.txt hello-world
container_id=$(cat cid.txt)
```